# Как это за ерунда - clubrelaxxxx.com и restme.net?

Tags: вирусы

Ситуация такая. По запросу [выборгская газета бесплатных объявлений](http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0+%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&clid=1823140&lr=2) выдаются ссылки на сайт, но при переходе по ним, пользователь попадает то на "Автоштраф", то на "Гороскоп".

При прямом заходе на сайт все нормально. При переходе по ссылкам из гугла - то же. Что это за паразит такой и как с ним бороться?

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте файл /etc/hosts или аналогичный в вашей ОС (которую вы не указали, кстати).

Comment: А вы свой проверили? У вас же такая же ситуация!

Comment: Проверил, перед тем как писать.